# Changes show up locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I've tried a bunch of different things as per suggestions, but cannot get it to work for me, what are some more alternatives?

When I git push, it says its already updated... is it a problem with uploading gem files, css? How can I know where it starts so I can then find an answer. It hasn't recorded any of my git push heroku master commands for a while apparently because there are many things missing & I just found out... Help!!!!

I'm pretty new at this, sorry guys!

Comment: Have you commited any code before pushing it..?

Comment: Yes I have. Doesn't work... I think there is something wrong with my configuration setup with Heroku although it was working before I must have messed it up somehow...

Answer (score 0):

You've got to run this from the command line:

```
git add . # Adds all files into the git
git commit -a -m "Your commit" # Creates commit 
git push heroku master # Pushes commit to Heroku
```

This will put your latest version of code onto Heroku, and then you've got to ensure you've got the database connectivity sorted (so your data updates persist in production)

Comment: I have been doing that, it doesn't work. Quick question, I've noticed a difference between my code in the gemfile.lock and the tutorials. Although I run a PC and he runs a Mac, is there supposed to be a difference or should I just copy that & perhaps that will resolve my problem. I say this because when I migrate, I see on one of the lines that gemfile.lock gets skipped... Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in passing a non-matching command to set my amazon bucket to what was on my production environment. Tutorial & huroku development center differed in syntax so I mixed them up apparently. So nothing after image uploading stage would work, all fixed now though! Thx